# Wamp server mail sendmail

Tags: php, wamp, sendmail

**So this is my sendmail.ini file**

```
*smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 465
smtp_ssl= ssl
default_domain=localhost
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=my gmail acc
auth_password=my gmail pass
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=localhost*
```

**and this is php.ini file**

```
*[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@domain.com
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"*
```

when i use mail functions it return false can someone help me ?

Comment: I don't have your answer but have a look at this, might help you knowing what is the actual error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function