# how to find when mail() failed

Tags: php, email, sendmail

```
<?php

if(function_exists('mail')) {
    echo 'mail() is enabled';

if (mail('XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'My Subject', 'test')) {
    echo("Your message has been sent successfully");
    } else {
    print_r(error_get_last());
    echo("Sorry, your message could not be sent");
}
} else {
    echo 'mail() is not enabled';
}  

?>
```

**output:**
mail() is enabledSorry, your message could not be sent

no error are displayed

here am using in live server  but how can i find error in this case ?? help us

Comment: This link may be helpful for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function

Comment: Which server you are using? is that cloud server?

Comment: @TECHNOMAN really i don't know only ftp details having

Comment: plz check by whois that which hosting it is using so based on that i can give my answer..or u can tell me the domain so i can find that myself

Comment: Also plz check by phpinfo() that mail function is enabled or not in your server

Comment: `mail.add_x_header  On On
mail.force_extra_parameters  no value no value
mail.log no value  no value`   @TECHNOMAN this what show in phpinfo()

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`