# Email is not sent when using mail function using php

Tags: php, html, database, email

I'm trying to  send an email confirmation to my email address (admin) after a user is registered into this form! Please how can i configure my sendmail?I'm using Xampp.The code works correctly and the message

> The email has been sent

is displayed but when opening my email address which is included into `$to` variable there is not any email in  inbox. This is my code:

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print ("<form action='register.php' method='post'>
    <p>Name
        <input type='text' name='firstname'  />
    </p>
    <p>Surname
        <input type='text' name='lastname' />
    </p>
    <p>Username
        <input type='text' name='username' />
    </p>
    <p>Password
        <input type='password' name='password' />
        </p>
        <p>Email <input type='text' name='email'/>  </p>
      Enter your CV: <p> <textarea name='cv' cols='60' rows='50'></textarea> </p>


  <input type='submit'  value='Register'/>  
</form>
        ");

if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['firstname'] )&&isset($_POST['lastname'])&&isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])
  &&isset($_POST['cv'])/*&&isset($_POST['notat'])&&isset($_POST['lendet'])*/&&isset($_POST['email'])){
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$cv=$_POST['cv'];
/*
$notat=$_POST['notat'];
$lendet=$_POST['lendet'];
*/

$query = "INSERT INTO  login (firstname, lastname, username,password,cv,email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$username','$password','$cv','$email')";
}
if ( !empty($firstname)&&!empty($lastname)&&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)&&!empty($cv)&&!empty($email))
{
  if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}

$to='backa.elda123@gmail.com';
$subject='Asking for permission';
$body='There is another registered student waiting for your approval!';
$headers='From:<arbi.backa@gmail.com>';
if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
  echo "mail sent to..";}
  else echo'errorr sending the email';
echo "YOU HAVE BEEN REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY!PLEASE WAIT FOR THE ADMIN APPROVAL!";
}
else echo "Fill in all the blank fields";
mysql_close($database);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check your Spam folder?

Comment: Yes I did.There isn;t any email in my spam too.

Comment: How have you configured your email sending stuff? In PHP, you need to configure sendmail.

Comment: See this please: [**Configure Sendmail with Wamp**](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp).

Comment: Agree with @Alexei's answer. You should use SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting PHP `mail` function usage is partially covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function).

After the e-mail is actually sent, it is a great that it will be treated as spam.

Most e-mail providers will not treat unauthenticated e-mails as valid ones and will consider them as spam. Gmail is no exception and you should use something like SMTP authentication. Please check at least one of the following:

1. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2. [Tutorial](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)

Comment: Could you please show me how to configure sendmailing in Xampp?