# Mail function always calling the else part

Tags: php, email

I have two domain name. For example https://example.com and https://example2.com.

I am sending test mail using mail function.

I am able to send the email from https://example.com and I am getting the success but the same code I am using for https://example2.com and I am not getting the email it's always calling the else part.

Test mail

```
<?PHP
$sender = 'xxx@xx.com';
$recipient = 'zzz@zz.com';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From: ' . $sender . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
echo "Error: Message not accepted";
$errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
echo $errorMessage;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";` you forgot to concatenate $headers

Comment: You're going to have to provide an error of some sort for us to help you. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function). And the `From` bit is overwritten in your header string (not using `.=` for MIME)

Comment: Yes, I updated that still same issue. @smoqadam thanks for the notice.

Comment: @rkeet, I update the code with $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message']; but it's not displaying any error. I am getting only echo "Error: Message not accepted";

Comment: Have your try [this](http://fasterland.net/sending-email-via-php-centos-7-using-sendmail.html)

Comment: @NgocNam, I am using Hostgator and GoDaddy for hosting. There is no issue with Hostgator hosting. I am not able to send from GoDaddy hosting

Comment: If everything is ok, then check with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

The `From` header is not valid as the next one is concatenated right after it:

```
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Should be something like:

```
// add \r\n
$headers = 'From: ' . $sender . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice that, I tried but still getting the same issue.https://prnt.sc/l6l39i

Answer (score 0):

Check if mail function is enabled on `example2.com` by using below:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mail' ) )
{
    echo 'mail() is available';
}
else
{
   echo 'mail() has been disabled';
}
```

If disabled, enable it via `php.ini` or in cPanel.

Comment: What I did I just comment out my if else condition and added your code to check and I got my output is "mail() is available".

Comment: Have you check error log on server or on your server document root?

Comment: Can you help me how to check that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple php mail function

```
$to      = $email_id;
$subject = "";
$message = "Your mail Body Content. you also use here HTML Tags for better performence. ";
$headers = 'From: xyz@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: xyz@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   echo "Message accepted";
}else{
   echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It's still showing else part. http://prntscr.com/l6l39i but the same code is working for my first domain

Comment: your form email id is belong to same domain or diffrent?

Comment: Yes, it's belong to same domain. and also I tried with other

Comment: The issue may be with your hosting provider can you just contact once hosting provider support team

Comment: Can you highlight the differences? What **exactly** needs to be changed from the original code to yours to make it work?