# How to send an email in Wordpress using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, send

For starters, I downloaded a Wordpress plugin that allows you to insert PHP snippets into a Wordpress site. I added this code hoping that it will send an email but I have not receeved anything yet. I have used two different snippet plugins, and I am not sure what could be causing the issue, or if there would be an easier way to go about doing this.

```
<?php

$to = 'mytestemail@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Test email';

$message = 'Test';

$headers = "From: The Sender name <myemailaddress@gmail.com>";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

?>
```

Comment: [How to Configure Your WordPress Email Settings (The RIGHT Way)](https://wpforms.com/how-to-configure-your-wordpress-email-settings-the-right-way/)

Comment: You don't even check the return value of `mail()` and most likely haven't read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) either. Did you even [search existing Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email+php) that could have led you to [How can I get the error message for the mail() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3186725/4299358)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). The good thing about `wp_mail` is that it uses whatever the default mail delivery service is configured in WordPress.

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

It's worth noting that the default PHP mailer is unlikely to work when running on your local machine.

I recommend setting up a mail plugin for WordPress that uses a third-party mail service like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) to send emails. I use [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

Comment: Depends: [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) always came with [mailtodisk](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxampp%5D+mailtodisk) for this purpose.